# What does "var" mean in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, how does keyword `var` work?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It means that the type of the local being declared will be inferred by the compiler based upon its first assignment:

```
// This statement:
var foo = "bar";
// Is equivalent to this statement:
string foo = "bar";
```

Notably, `var` does not define a variable to be of a dynamic type.  So this is NOT legal:

```
var foo = "bar";
foo = 1; // Compiler error, the foo variable holds strings, not ints
```

`var` has only two uses:

1. It requires less typing to declare variables, especially when declaring a variable as a nested generic type.
2. It must be used when storing a reference to an object of an anonymous type, because the type name cannot be known in advance: `var foo = new { Bar = "bar" };`

You cannot use `var` as the type of anything but locals.  So you cannot use the keyword `var` to declare field/property/parameter/return types.

Comment: @cdhowie What if while saying, `var foo = new Foo()`, `foo` could be of type `Foo` or any of its super classes. How can that be any legal?

Comment: @Djack It's not legal, and that's not the case.  `var foo = new Foo();` is the same thing as `Foo foo = new Foo();`, which means that `foo` can contain a `Foo` reference, or a reference to an object any `Foo` **sub**type, *not* a `Foo` **super**type.

Answer (score 16):

It means the data type is derived (implied) from the context.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables
>   that are declared at method scope can
>   have an implicit type var. An
>   implicitly typed local variable is
>   strongly typed just as if you had
>   declared the type yourself, but the
>   compiler determines the type. The
>   following two declarations of i are
>   functionally equivalent:

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

`var` is useful for eliminating keyboard typing and visual noise, e.g.,

```
MyReallyReallyLongClassName x = new MyReallyReallyLongClassName();
```

becomes

```
var x = new MyReallyReallyLongClassName();
```

but can be overused to the point where readability is sacrificed.

Answer (score 8):

"var" means the compiler will determine the explicit type of the variable, based on usage. For example,

```
var myVar = new Connection();
```

would give you a variable of type Connection.

Answer (score 8):

It declares a type based on what is assigned to it in the initialisation.

A simple example is that the code:

```
var i = 53;
```

Will examine the type of 53, and essentially rewrite this as:

```
int i = 53;
```

Note that while we can have:

```
long i = 53;
```

This won't happen with var. Though it can with:

```
var i = 53l; // i is now a long
```

Similarly:

```
var i = null; // not allowed as type can't be inferred.
var j = (string) null; // allowed as the expression (string) null has both type and value.
```

This can be a minor convenience with complicated types. It is more important with anonymous types:

```
var i = from x in SomeSource where x.Name.Length > 3 select new {x.ID, x.Name};
foreach(var j in i)
  Console.WriteLine(j.ID.ToString() + ":" + j.Name);
```

Here there is no other way of defining `i` and `j` than using `var` as there is no name for the types that they hold.

Answer (score 6):

Did you ever hated to write such variable initializers?

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerialzer(typeof(int))
```

So, starting with C# 3.0, you can replace it with

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerialzer(typeof(int))
```

One notice: Type is resolved during compilation, so no problems with performance. But Compiler should be able to detect type during build step, so code like `var xmlSerializer;` won't compile at all.

Answer (score 1):

- As the name suggested, var is variable without any data type.
- If you don't know which type of data will be returned by any method, such cases are good for using var.
- var is Implicit type which means system will define the data type itself. The compiler will infer its type based on the value to the right of the "=" operator.
- int/string etc. are the explicit types as it is defined by you explicitly.
- Var can only be defined in a method as a local variable
- Multiple vars cannot be declared and initialized in a single statement. For example, var i=1, j=2; is invalid.

```
int i = 100;// explicitly typed 
var j = 100; // implicitly typed
```

Answer (score -1):

var is a "contextual keyword" in C# meaning you can only use it as a local variable implicitly in the context of the same class that you are using the variable. If you try to use it in a class that you call from "Main" or some other exterior class, or an interface for example you will get the error CS0825 < https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0825 >

See the remarks about when you can and can't use it in the documentation here: < https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables#remarks >

Basically, you should only use this when you are declaring a variable with an implicit value such as "var myValue = "This is the value"; This saves a little time in comparison to saying "string" for example but IMHO not much time is saved and places a constraint on the scalability of your project.