# Linq to SQL brief question

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, windows

I have a query below. although can anyone point out what "from p" means? and also "var r"?

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(); 
            var r = from p in db.Products 
                    where p.UnitPrice > 15 // If unit price is greater than 15...
                    select p; // select entries
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r` is the composed query - an `IQueryable<Product>` or similar; note the query *has not yet executed* - it is ***just*** a pending query. `var` means "compiler, figure out the *type* of r from the expression on the right". You could have stated it explicitly in this case, but not all. But it wouldn't add any value, so `var` is fine.

`p` is a convenience marker for each product; the query is "for each product (p), restricting to those with unit price greater than 15 (`where p > 15`), select that product (`select p`) as a result.

Ultimately this compiles as:

```
IQueryable<Product> r =
    db.Products.Where(p => p.UnitPrice > 15);
```

(in this case, a final `.Select(p => p)` is omitted by the compiler, but with a *non-trivial* projection, or a *trivial* query, the `.Select(...)` is retained)

Comment: Thank you, very well answered!

Answer (score 1):

The `p` means each specific item in the collection referenced (`db.Products`). See [`from`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx) on MSDN.

`var` is syntactic sugar - it resolves to the type returned from the LINQ query, assigning the type to the variable `r`. See [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) on MSDN.

For better understanding of LINQ, I suggest reading through [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746).

Answer (score 0):

`from p` means any record from `db.Product` and `var` r means the `collection of p`

overall whole statements means give me all those records(p) from `db.Products` where `p.UnitPrice` is greater than 15

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c) question to know more about `var`