# Pass a var type variable to a function as reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, var

Here is a sample piece of code where im trying to send a var type variable to another function as a reference parameter.

```
 Type type = Type.GetType(te1.GetValue("class1"));
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("fnc1");
        var obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I cant use (class1)Activator.CreateInstance(type) since the variable class1      will     be decided at runtime. That's why im using reflection here.

```
   method.Invoke(obj1, new object[] { });     
    class2 cls2= new class2 ();
    cls2.fnc2(ref obj1);//getting error  'cannot convert object to class type'
```

Im getting error as the fnc2 function receive parameter as a type of class1.

```
 public string fnc2(ref class1 obj3)
    {
    }
```

How i can handle this? I need to get the parameter as a type of class1 using reflection. So i used the type var. I cant use dynamic since im using framework 3.5.

My requirement is create a object of class1>> execute a function of class1>> retain the object and pass that object to another function of class2 and process there.Also the name class1 and class2 will be decided dynamically and cannot be hard coded.

Comment: try this line
var obj1 = (class1)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

Comment: you're creating an instance of 'class1' while you're passing it to a method which expects to receive refrence of 'class2'. this is not possible bro

Comment: what is `te1`? (I assume you are using reflection here). And later in the last snippet of code you have access to type `class1`, then why are you reflecting?

Comment: The area where the function fnc2 invoke and the define the function needs to be redesigned. I dont know how to send parameter and later access it in another function. My requirement is create a object of class1>> execute a function of class1>> retain the object and pass that object to another function of class2 and process there.

Answer (score 3):

[`var` is *not* a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c?lq=1). Rather it tells the compiler to "automatically determine the type" (and saves typing). Hover the mouse over the `obj1` in the next line and Visual Studio will pop up a handy little box saying what the *actual* type is resolved to - as the error message indicates this is, well, Object.

(Some of the following may be outdated after updates to the question, but the same principles apply - the expression *must* be cast as appropriate type, which must be determined at compile-time, before it can be used as anything besides Object.)

A "solution" is just to cast the result of the Activator result (because we *know* this to be the case):

```
var obj1 = (class1)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
// same as: class1 obj1 = (class1)..
```

However, since we know this then we could avoid all that and use the following, which is boring:

```
var obj1 = new class1();
// same as: class1 obj1 = new class1();
```

So, now to the Y problem: *this cannot be done for an arbitrary type* and a cast *is* required. The types known by the compiler which can used as such in code *must* be known at compile-time; they cannot be directly resolved from run-time values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the type of `obj1` is of the type your `fnc2` expects then you could use reflection like so:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(te1.GetValue("class1"));
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("fnc1");
object obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

method.Invoke(obj1, new object[] {});
class2 cls2 = new class2();

cls2.GetType().GetMethod("fnc2").Invoke(cls2, new[] {obj1});
```

This retrieves the method called `fnc2` (assuming there's only one with that name, no overloads) and invokes it with `obj1`. If there are overloads, you will need this [GetMethod variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

On a sidenote, using var in this case is really not that useful. For clarity, I think you should just use `object`.