# My first attempt at an application framework using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

So I'm writing a framework for my projects.

This framework should take the PT out of starting new projects by providing a generic foundation upon which the project is built.

The framework includes:

- A generic db context to which is provided by the application a database name
- Generic data models that include "common" data such as a user model with an email address and password property
- Generic CRUD functionality for the generic data models

So far I feel like I've got stuck early on in my attempt to make my DbContext class as generic as possible. See below:

```
public class DataEntities : DbContext
{
    public string _databaseName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName
    { 
        get
        {
            if (String.Compare(_databaseName, String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                return "LYSDatabase";
            }
            else
            {
                return _databaseName;
            }
        }
        set;
    }
    public Initializer _initializer { get; set; }

    public enum Initializer
    {
        DropCreateDatabaseAlways = 1,
        DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges = 2,
        CreateDatabaseIfNotExists = 3
    }

    public DataEntities()
        : base(DatabaseName)
    {
        var Init;
        switch (_initializer)
        {
            case Initializer.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists:
                Init = new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataEntities>();
                break;
            case Initializer.DropCreateDatabaseAlways:
                Init = new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataEntities>();
                break;
            case Initializer.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges:
                Init = new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataEntities>();
                break;
        }

        Database.SetInitializer<DataEntities>(Init);
    }
}
```

I have 2 errors in this code and I've been unable to find a solution to either of them:

On the line `: base(DatabaseName)`:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'LYSFramework.DataEntities.DatabaseName.get'

As neither the class nor the constructor are static, I don't understand what it is that I've done wrong here.

On the line `var Init;`

> Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized

It is implicitly typed because I don't know what type to set it to yet. It should get its type later in the `switch`.

My questions are as follows:

1. How do I use the string property's value in the base inheritance on the constructor?
2. What type should I set `Init` to before I use it? (Ideally it should basically just be null I guess).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Extract `"LYSDatabase"` into a `const` and use it when calling `: base(DATABASE_NAME);

Comment: `var Init;` you need to initialize it to a value what is it `boolean, string, integer, etc...` this is very obvious what the error is telling you btw

Comment: @MethodMan yes it is, but as I'm deterministically setting it's type based on what value was selected from the enum, that's where the confusion comes from

Comment: This is simply not how the `var` keyword works. It doesn't mean "this variable can be of multiple types". See perhaps [What does “var” mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c)

Comment: Yes I know that. How can I get it to work that the variable *can* be multiple types?

Comment: You need to define an interface that each of your "multiple types" implements.  Then declare your `Init` variable as that interface type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I use the string property's value in the base inheritance on the constructor?

When the `DataEntities` constructor is called, the first thing it tries to do is call the `DbContext` (base class) constructor.  At this point, you don't have a complete instance of the `DataEntities` class, so you can't pass the instance property `DatabaseName` into the base constructor.  You'll probably need to modify the `DataEntities` constructor to take the database as a parameter so that you can pass it on to the base class constructor.

> What type should I set `Init` to before I use it?

Once `Init` is declared, its type cannot be changed.  `var` can only be used to declare a variable if it is initialized immediately so that the compiler can tell what type it is.

You hae to declare `Init` with a type that is compatible with anything you want to assign it later.  You could do this a few ways:

- [Recommended] Create an interface `IDatabaseInitializer` that each of your types implements, and then change your declaration to `IDatabaseInitializer Init;`
- Declare `Init` as an `object`, since every class in C# implicitly inherits from `object`.
- Use the `dynamic` keyword (not recommended - this leads to very fragile code).

Comment: No need to create a new interface, all 3 types already implement [`IDatabaseInitializer<DataEntities>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323(v=vs.113).aspx) (those 3 types in his switch are part of EF, not made by the OP)

Comment: Well... That didn't make sense the first time I read it but that might have been because I was on the phone. Works now so thanks :)