# MVC model coding with table model and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi I have some coding issue here, what I am trying to do is based on the input `SYSID`, find the list of name from table, just for testing purpose.

**Model:**

```
public DbSet<firsttest> firsttests { get; set; }
```

**Table:**

```
  [Table("FirstTest")]
    public class firsttest
    { 
        public firsttest(){}

        [Column("sysId")]
        public long SysId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/FirstTest/{SysId}")]
    public List<String> Name(long SYSID)
    {
        using (AContext db = new AContext())
        {
            var query = db.firsttests.Where(a => 1 == 1);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SYSID.ToString()))
            {
                query = query.Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SYSID)).Select(a => a.Name);
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

**The error is :** cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.Iqueryable(string) to System.Linq.Iqueryable(Model.firsttest)

Any idea how to modify the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

`var query = db.firsttests.Where(a => 1 == 1);`

returns an IQueryable collection of `firsttest` entities. So the type of variable `query` is `IQueryable<firsttest>` (*because of type inference*)

But later you are trying to set a different type (`IQueryable<string>`)to that variable when you select the `Name` property.

```
query = query.Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SYSID)).Select(a => a.Name);
```

That is why you are getting this compile error.

Also there is no point in the string null or empty check. long value is not nullable. So you need to have a valid numeric long value for the route to work. So simply use the parameter in your where clause.

```
[Route("api/FirstTest/{SysId}")]
public List<String> Name(long SysId)
{ 
   using (var db = new AContext())
   {
     return db.firsttests   // here the type is IQueryable<firsttest>
              .Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SysId)) 
              .Select(a => a.Name) // here the type is IQueryable<string>
              .ToList();  // here the type of List<string>
   }
}
```

Comment: So the only choice I have is to add `select` after `return` line? is there any explicit conversion method I have to convert explicitly from IQueryable<string> to IQueryable<firsttest>?

Comment: You can select and keep it in a variable and return or simply do it in a one line like i did. Eventually the compiler will optimize it and generate code like the one generated by the one liner.

Comment: Your code explains perfectly for me, just curious, no explicit conversion against this line? `query = query.Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SYSID)).Select( a => a.Name)`, which will convert IQueryable<string> to IQueryable<firsttest> for me?

Comment: No. you cannot convert a collection of firsttest to a collection of string like that. you can set the value to a different varibale though (`var nameList=query.Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SYSID)).Select( a => a.Name)`. Then return that after calling ToList() as your method return type is List.

Comment: I see, thanks for your detail answer and explanations ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/FirstTest/{SysId}")]
public List<String> Name(long SYSID)
{
    using (SpaContext db = new SpaContext())
    {
        var query = db.firsttests.Where(a => 1 == 1);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SYSID.ToString()))
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SYSID));
        }
        return query.Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter the results there in the if block and  then project just before returning the `List<string>` like:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SYSID.ToString()))
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.SysId.Equals(SYSID)); // only filter here
}
return query.Select(a => a.Name).ToList(); // now project the result finally
```

This behaviour you are seeing is because of the nature of the way `var` works in C#.

When you write `var query = db.firsttests.Where(a => 1 == 1);` , the variable `query` is now of type `IQueryable<Model.firsttest>` and now down in the code you cannot assign to variable `query` a reference of different type which in your case after project the result will become `System.Linq.Iqueryable<string>`.

You can read about it in more detail the following :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

[What does "var" mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c)

Comment: this works for me! But why I cannot specify the `select` before `return` like my code? Do I need explicit conversion method?

Comment: it's because when you write `var query = db.firsttests.Where(a => 1 == 1);`, the `query` is now strongly typed with `IQueryable<Model.firsttest>` not down in the code you cannot assign query reference of different type which in your query will become `System.Linq.Iqueryable<string>`