# Better way to converting string [123,234,...] to List<int> and back

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Basically, I am trying to convert what appears to be an array of integer values stored in a string type.

```
[123,234,345,456] // example
```

Currently, I am doing the following to convert string to `List<int>` or an `int[]:`

```
var intList = "[123,234,345,456]".Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).Tolist();
```

Perform required operations `(sort, add, remove)` on the `list` and `convert` it back to a `string`:

```
string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", intList));
```

But then this got me thinking. The data that I am working with looks like `JSON`. Surely there must a more direct way of `converting` the `string` into an `array of integers`?

I looked at using `JArray.Parse(string)` from `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` but isn't that just adding an extra layer of complexity as now I am dealing with `JArray<JToken>` instead of standard `int[]`.

If anyone has a neater solution that doesn't involve adding `methods`, `extensions` or `libraries` I would appreciate if you can share your knowledge.

Comment: what is the exptected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON list to int array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341784/parsing-json-list-to-int-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You can use regex as well,

Comment: If your input really is that simple you could use a regex, but that will soon get very cumbersome if your inout-format changes - e.g. if you have doubles instead of ints.

Comment: `JsonDataContractSerializer` can do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: What do you mean by "extra layer of complexity"? are you concerned about performance? JSON seems to be more readable, it is fast as well. it's designed to work with strings anyway...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are correct - JSON *can* do this for you:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string test = "[123,234,345,456]";

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(test);

            // This prints "123, 234, 345, 456"

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));

            string andBackAgain = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

            // This prints "[123,234,345,456]"

            Console.WriteLine(andBackAgain);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but was unaable to produce. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to parse numbers with double quotes then

```
    string input = @"[123,234,345,456]";
    string pattern = @"\d+";
    var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "\"$&\"");
    result.Dump();
    //["123","234","345","456"]
```

or to parse whole object inside array braces

```
    string input = @"[123,234,345,456]";
    string pattern = @"(\d+\s*,?\s*)+";
    var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "\"$&\"");
    result.Dump();
    //["123,234,345,456"]
```