# Correctly declaring an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax

Have tried looking into it, but not even sure on how to google this.

I know this gives an error `var intArray = {1,2,3,4};`and that it has to be

`var intArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4};` or `int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4};`

but I can't seem to find an actual reason WHY I can't use the first one.

Since at the very least I'd expect it to make an object[] by default.

So basically what I'm asking is: Why is the first one incorrect/not allowed.

```
        var intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; //incorrect
        var numArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; //correct
        int[] digArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; //correct
```

~Suggestions for a better title are welcome, didn't really know how to ask this.~

Comment: The error message is clear enough na? : Cannot initialize an implicitly-typed local variable with an array initializer

Comment: Second point of this answer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c

Comment: You can drop the `int[]` i.e: `var intArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local variable initializer (the **var**) does not know what type you are giving it when you explicitly defining values.

So this:

```
var intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Would potentially work once you give it a type:

```
int intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

But of course we know that you cant store 4 values inside a single int, so need to declare an array.

```
int[] digArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

> Since at the very least I'd expect it to make an object[] by default.

There are so many variations of what a var = {1,2,3,4} could be that there is no way for your IDE to compile that code and store it in memory. Do you reference it as 1 object? 4 objects? A string value? Is it a JSON schema?

Comment: This answer doesn't make clear **why** the compiler cannot infer the type of `{ 1 }` while it does for `new[] { 1 }`. For better explanation, see the question referenced as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intArray = new int[]{}
int[] digArray = {}
```

These two specify the size of the array. Something that has to be done when creating arrays.
Where as

```
var numArray
```

does not.

If you dont want to define the size of an array you can use a list.

Comment: Please read Eric Lippert's answer in the question I referenced as duplicate. Technically, this was possible, but the language design team just decided against it.

Comment: @dymanoid Seems like an odd choice to never implement the feature. I suppose we always have lists

Comment: @dymanoid thanks, yeah, forgot about the implicit part, most likely would've found that one as well if I'd googled on that... Was too focused on the Array part I suppose.

Comment: @JamesS your answer isn't really an answer though, since, sure, var doesn't define a size, but neither does int[]. The sizing happens for both of those in the "{,,,}" part. The thing that I just find stupid is that the compiler can't see that the "var" should be replaced with the type "int[]" or at the very least "object[]".

Comment: @DennisVanhout [] without a number inside state that the array could be any size. For exmaple int array = new int[5] has a size of 5. int array = new int[] has an unknown size

Comment: `int array = new int[5]` is not a valid C# code, neither is `int array = new int[]`.

Comment: Sorry. int[ ] array = new int[ ] and int[ ] array = new int[5]